# Problema ao Injetar um Serviço no Controller: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, injeção-de-dependência

Estou recebendo o erro abaixo ao tentar injetar um serviço dentro de um *controler*. Já verifiquei a minha configuração no Statup.cs.

**Erro:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. 
>   **InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AE.Infra.Persistence.AEContext' while attempting to activate 'AE.Infra.Repository.UserRepositorylmpr.***

```
// Configurações da injeção de dependência
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml"));
        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("json", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserServiceImpl>();

    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepositoryImpl>();

    //Dependency Injection of GenericRepository
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));           
}
```

Também criei um projeto de infra dentro da minha *solution*, onde ela possui um `DBContext` onde realizo a conexão:

```
public partial class AEContext : DbContext
{
    // Configurações do contexto
}
```

Minha classe **`UserRepositoryImpl`** extende uma **`GenericRepository<User>`** e implementa a interface **`IUserRepository`**. Segue um modelo de um cenário de teste:

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl : GenericRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepositoryImpl(AEContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public async Task<User> FindByEmail(string email)
    {
        return await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email.Equals(email));
    }
}
```

Meu **GenericRepository** está extremamente simples, somente para cunho de teste de cenário:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{

    protected readonly AEContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dataSet;

    public GenericRepository(AEContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dataSet = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Você não fez o registro da classe `AEContext`. `services.AddScoped<AEContext>();`

Comment: Obrigado cara, funcionou. Desde ontem tentando resolver esse problema e não estava prosseguindo.

Comment: Tranquilo, de nada. Postei uma resposta com mais alguns detalhes.

Comment: Tem gente classificando a questão como ruim... não entendi nada! rsrsr

Comment: Acho que a mensagem de erro como imagem não foi uma boa ideia, você também poderia encurtar um pouco o código e deixar apenas os pontos mais importantes. Eu não sou nenhum especialista em escrever questões aqui, mas vou editar seu post e tentar dar uma melhorada na estrutura dele conforme algumas "práticas" que o pessoal costuma gostar.

Comment: Blz! Obrigado pela dica... Sempre segui boas práticas aqui a risca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer que as instâncias sejam criadas automaticamente, você precisa registrar toda e qualquer dependência delas. Isso inclui registrar uma instância de `AEContext` para ser injetada no que você chama de **`Repository`**.

Btw, eu não tenho certeza se você pretende que a instância seja por escopo ou transiente, usei o método `AddScoped` baseado no código existente.

Então, falta fazer isso no método `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddScoped<AEContext>();
}
```